# Find an example of subsets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Let $M = \{1, 2, 3, \ldots, 2^n\}$. Nonempty subsets $M_1, \ldots, M_k \subseteq M$ are such that $|M_i| = 2^{n-1}$.
Consider the cardinality of sets' intersection $f_{i,j} = | M_i \bigcap M_j |$.

If the number of subsets satisfies $k=2^{n-1}$ and $f = \max_\limits{i,j; \; i \neq j} f_{i,j} < 2^{n-2}$, find an example of such subsets.

Comment: does $\left \{ 1,2, \ldots 2^n \right \}$ refer to the set of natural numbers $\leq 2^n$ or powers of two? Please clarify.

Comment: ${1, 2, \ldots, 2^n}$ refer to the set of natural numbers.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint*

Try with $n$ small and find such an example, but add also the condition that for each subset $M_i$, its complementary $M-M_i$ is also one of the subsets you took.

Now try build them through inductions, splitting $M$ in half, etc. etc.

Comment: An example for $n=4$ is easy to build, but it's not possible to apply induction for large $n$ only by dividing the set $M$ in half.

Comment: you have to complete ;) When $|M|=2^{n+1}$ you can split it in half and use induction on every half. Then you get a lot of subsets and you can combine them in order to find the right $M_i$s

Comment: Okay, I split $M$ ($|M| = 2^{n+1}$) in a half and prove by induction that I can construct $2^{n-1}$ subsets ($2^{n-2}$ from the first half and $2^{n-2}$ from the second) of size $2^{n-1}$, but the size must be $2^{n}$. If the subset $M_i$ is included in this list, I can't take the complement $M-M_i$, because with other subsets it intersects more than $2^{n-2}$ elements.

Comment: *Last Hint*: Call $L_i$ the subsets from the first half and $R_i$ the subsets from the second half. Suppose that $L_1\cup L_2$ is the first half and $R_1\cup R_2$ is the second half. Then $L_1\cup R_1$ is of cardinality $2^n$ and its complementary is $L_2\cup R_2$.